# Extensive Logarithm Question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$2^{x+1}=2^{x+2}$

How do you solve this equation?

Answer (score 2):

Notice that both sides have the same base.  So you can just equate the exponents and solve for $x$.  That is, solve the equation $x+1 = x+2$.  But notice that that equation has no solution.  Therefore the original equation, assuming it's correctly written, has no solution.

Answer (score 2):

It translates to 
$$
2^{x + 1} = 2 \cdot 2^{x + 1} = 2^{x + 1} + 2^{x + 1} \iff \\
0 = 2^{x + 1}
$$
after subtracting $2^{x+1}$ from both sides. The last equation has no solution $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: How do you get $0$?

Answer (score 0):

Use properties of logarithms. So take the natural log of both sides:

$\ln(2^{x+1}) = \ln(2^{x+2})$

Then you can bring down the exponent of what's inside your natural log function as a coefficient:

$(x+1)\ln2 = (x+2)\ln2$

Divide both sides by $\ln2$, you have $x+1 = x+2$, which, as stated above, has no solution.